# Переадресация запросов по данным из тела запроса

Tags: java, nginx, spring-mvc, маршрутизация, микросервисы

Существует сервис с "кучей" контроллеров. Стоит задача "распилить" данный сервис на микросервисы.

Сами микросервисы будут крутится на самостоятельных машинах.

Основная проблема в том, что есть некий роут(`http://mydomain/myservice/srv/data`), на который приходит разного типа запросы.

А логика после вызывается на основании значения в поле запроса. То есть два запроса:

`<request type="getname" val="1"/>` и `<request type="balance" val="1"/>`

должны уходить на разные логики будующих микросервисов(получение имени должно перенаправится, к примеру, на `http://mydomain/myservice1/data/name`, а получение баланса на `http://mydomain/myservice2/data/balance` ).

По факту сейчас вижу такие решения(если они возможны, конечно):

1. Анализ на точке входа(ngix)
2. Написание сервиса-маршрутизатора(анализирует и, грубо говоря, перенаправляет запросы RestTemplate'ом, к примеру, на микросервисы)

**Вопрос**: какие штатные средства есть для анализа содержимого тела запроса и дальнейшего перенаправления на другой микросервис?

Очень не хочется городить "велосипед" с п.2

Может есть какие либо библиотеки для подобных целей, где можно лаконично это реализовать, к примеру.

**UPD**: рассматриваются и легковестные библиотеки, с помощью которых можно реализовать такой роутинг, основанный на содержимом тела запроса. Т.к. дали ясно понять, что вариант с настройкой `ngix` - крайний

Comment: встроенный js, встроенный perl, собранная lua и т.п.

Comment: @norbornen Уже, видимо, все таки надо смотреть в сторону библиотек `Java`. Вариант с настройкой роута на `ngix` - остается как самый последний(((

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вообщем пришлось все же написать свой сервис.

Использовали:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-gateway</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Роутинг реализовали следующим образом:

```
@Configuration
public class Routing {

    @Bean
    public RouteLocator routeLocator(RouteLocatorBuilder builder) {

        return builder.routes()
                .route("NameService",
                        r -> r.path("http://mydomain/myservice/srv/data*")
                        .and().method(HttpMethod.POST)
                        .and().readBody(String.class, b -> b.contains("\"name\""))
                        .uri("http://mydomain/myservice1/data/name")
                )
                .route("BalanceService",
                        r -> r.path("http://mydomain/myservice/srv/data*")
                        .and().method(HttpMethod.POST)
                        .and().readBody(String.class, b -> b.contains("\"balance\""))
                        .uri("http://mydomain/myservice2/data/balance")
                )
                .build();
    }

}
```

приятно удивила `netty` по производительности)).

Также были эксперементы с реализацией через прокси:

```
@GetMapping("/srv/data")
public Mono<ResponseEntity<byte[]>> mixed(ProxyExchange<byte[]> proxy) throws Exception {

        return Mono.fromCallable(() -> 
                    ......
                    ......
                    return proxy
                            .uri("http://mydomain/myservice1/data/name").get();
                    ......
                    ......

                    return proxy
                            .uri("http://mydomain/myservice2/data/balance").get();
                });

    }
```

В варианте с прокси использовали также получение данных из БД и доп. анализ их(в куче с теми, что пришли в теле запроса)